# DataTable.GetChanges() keeps returning NULL

Tags: .net, datatable

I am trying to get all the rows that exist in `allData` but not in `removeData`

```
public static DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable allData, 
    DataTable removeData) 
{
    removeData.Merge(allData);
    DataTable newData = removeData.GetChanges(); 
    removeData.RejectChanges();
    return newData;
}
```

`removeData` is empty prior to the call in this case (just a new DataTable();)

But `newData` always has a value of null after the `DataTable newData = removeData.GetChanges();` line

Final Solution:

```
    public static DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable allData, DataTable removeData) 
    {
        DataTable duplicate = allData.Clone();
        foreach (DataRow row in allData.Rows)
        {
            duplicate.ImportRow(row);
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in duplicate.Rows)
        {
            row.SetAdded();
        } 

        removeData.Merge(duplicate);
        DataTable newData = removeData.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
        removeData.RejectChanges();
        allData.RejectChanges();
        return newData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `removeData` DataTable needs to have the same columns/fields as `allData`.  In other words, it can't just be a new DataTable().

Comment: So, now I'm writing the old data and schema to the filesystem (WriteXml and WriteXmlSchema), I then load them into removeData (with ReadXmlSchema and ReadXml).  And allData contains the data from the db (which has 2 more records than what is in the filesystem xml).  So when I get to this code I see that allData has 21 rows and removeData has 19.  The merge then causes removeData to have 40!  And then GetChanges is still returning null

Comment: Fixed the primary keys so that when I merge they both have 21 rows, but GetChanges still returns NULL!

Comment: Had to work some mojo to get the added rows to be marked as added, I updated the original question with the final solution

Answer (score 1):

The [DataTable.GetChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is dependent on the [DataRow.RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. For each row in a pair of DataTables, a [DataTable.Merge()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will either preserve their 'RowState' property, or reset it to 'Unchanged' (depending on the overload that you choose to use).
This means that when you merge two DataTables with rows that have 'Unchanged' RowStates, the merged table will also contain 'Unchanged' rows and the DataTable.GetChanges method will return null or Nothing.